# Custom sign-in button not saving sign-in status

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I used google's premade, custom google sign-in button but it doesn't save sign-in status. It will say I'm signed and print my information in the console without any problems, but as soon as I reload the page, I won't be signed in anymore. Is there a way to avoid this? I want to be auto signed in until I call `signOut()`.

My code so far (Sorry for clutter):

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2ef8ddb166.js" crossorigin="anonymous" SameSite="Lax"></script>
  <script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '260399017237-rd58msbkiq4jc8cr6pkqqq2jg1tg85ma.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error, undefined, 2);
        });
  }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">

    #googleBtn {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2D90DE;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}


#googleBtn:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#googleBtn:hover .fa-google{
    background: conic-gradient(from -45deg, #ea4335 110deg, #4285f4 90deg 188deg, #34a853 180deg 270deg, #fbbc05 270deg) 73% 55%/150% 150% no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-google {
  color: #2D90DE;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a id="googleBtn"><i class="fa fa-google fa-4x" style="padding-top: 8px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <script>startApp();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can save the login information in the cookie or local storage. Place a method to check local storage values every time and add a redirection accordingly.

Comment: I don't know what information I am supposed to store.

Comment: you must be receiving some token in the google response, u can store it. Or the user response